# Chrome argument "--disable-infobars" does not work with Chrome 65

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, chromedriver

When I start Chrome by Chromedriver with Selenium, Infobar is not hiddened.
Because chrome has updated `version 65.x.x.x.`
Here is my code:

```
[VB.NET]

Dim driverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService

driverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = True

Dim chromeOp As New ChromeOptions

chromeOp.AddArgument("--disable-infobars")

chromeOp.AddArgument("--start-maximized")

CRDriver = New ChromeDriver(driverService, chromeOp)
```

Comment: downgrade Chrome?

Comment: Thank Yu Zhang. Our applications is for many users. Downgrade Google Chrome is not a viable solution. Any other solutions?

Comment: It`s very bad for me, becouse I use click by coordinates and infobar knocks coordinates (( so, now I can`t use fullscreen mode !!!

Comment: I also need this flag [--disable-infobars] in my automation test coz it captures image and validate it

Comment: It changes dimention of visible part of browser. It isn't good for me.

Comment: try to use **--no-startup-window**, it helps me

Comment: Same as reshma. And the bar has a shadow which affects anything directly under it. And you can't even get rid of it by clicking on the close X - it just goes black. It's B*****.

Answer (score 3):

Disable-infobars flag has been removed per this merged commit below.

for more details check here:
1. [chromium.googlesource.com](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/d869ab3350d8ebd95222b4a47adf87ce3d3214b1)
2. [chromium-review.googlesource.com](https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/chromium/src/+/857604)

> This flag is no longer needed by the perf testing infrastructure and can be misused for malicious purposes, so remove it.

**Update April 18, 2018:**

--disable-infobars has been added back to Chrome 66.0.3359.117.

Comment: But this has little effect, because infobar will change the visible part.

Comment: I beg to differ.  the infobar does hide elements behind it, blocking Selenium from interacting with those elements.  I'll be following the links to the chromium team for more info.  Thanks for the links!

Comment: #false. This kills my visual tests... THANKS GOOGLE

Comment: The infobar doesn't block any elements based on my test. The top of the webpage starts below the infobar.

Comment: I think they have re-implemented it.  https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=820453#c6  No idea when/if it will be back in Chrome though.

Answer (score 1):

The alternative I'm using to solve this issue is using excludeSwitches: ['enable-automation'] on chromeOptions.

But after this, I'm still having an issue with Disable Extensions box, it's supposed to be hidden using the 'disable-extensions' flag on args, but isn't working for me. If someone can test it and report back should be great.