# How to disable infobar from Chrome

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, c#

The option to disable infobar `"Chrome is being controlled by automated test software"` was removed from Chrome.

> Chrome version: 65.0.3325.146
>
> Chrome driver: 2.36
>
> OS: Windows 10

I used the code below:

```
ChromeOptions option = new ChromeOptions();
option.AddArguments("disable-infobars");
driver = new ChromeDriver(option);
```

Do we have any solutions, how to disable infobar, please ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome argument "--disable-infobars" does not work with Chrome 65](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/32437/chrome-argument-disable-infobars-does-not-work-with-chrome-65)

Comment: Chrome 76 has removed the disable-infobars command line shortcut.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Disabling infobars is not supported anymore by Chromium.

According to [them](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/d869ab3350d8ebd95222b4a47adf87ce3d3214b1),

> Remove --disable-infobars.
>
> This flag is no longer needed by the perf testing infrastructure and
>   can be misused for malicious purposes, so remove it.

So either you can downgrade your chrome version or start ignoring the infobar in the new version.

Comment: It looks like they may be re-implementing it, given feedback from several user complaints.  We could be playing ping-pong with this one for a while... https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=820453#c6

Answer (score 4):

Solution for Java, Python, Ruby, JS, Protractor

https://help.applitools.com/hc/en-us/articles/360007189411--Chrome-is-being-controlled-by-automated-test-software-notification

When using java, you can code like this:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions()
.addArguments("--disable-infobars") // no longer works any more 
// here is the solution 
.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", new String[]{"enable-automation"}) ;
// put it as args
ChromeDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
// OK,enjoy 
webDriver.get("https://www.google.com");
```

Comment: Please don't post links without explanation. The article is a good one, but you should post a summary of the article before directing users to it.

Comment: Python 

chrome_options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-automation'])

    Note that the "--" that you use in older versions of chrome_options are omitted .

Answer (score 2):

You can try these two experimental options:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();    
options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", 
        Collections.singletonList("enable-automation"));
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: The problem will not be solved by this code. Other suggestions, please.

Comment: This solution worked for me in Selenium

Answer (score 0):

Disable infobar in Chrome is working fine, even in the latest chrome version 69 along with chromedriver version 2.42.

Steps to Disable infobars in Chrome.

---

- Define ChromeOptions

---

```
    ChromeOptions co = new ChromeOptions();
    co.addArguments("disable-infobars");
```

---

- Add ChromeOptions to desired capabilities

---

```
    DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities();
    dc.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, co);
```

---

- Add DesiredCapabilities to Webdriver

---

```
    driver = new ChromeDriver(dc);
```

---